# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/adView'). even after AdView have that id

Tags: android, xml

I am working on an android app but after I add AdView it shows error Error:(23, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/adView').

XML Code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_lock"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:elevation="4dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/addUnit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

still i am getting the error. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have declared your framelayout above your adview, add @+id instead of @id

```
android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `android:layout_above="@+id/adView"` 
It will work.